# How to group by and count based on a condition

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am new Access and I framing a query to group a table based on a field and get a count of records based on a condition.

Table:

```
Category       Status
Pen            Open
Pencil         Open
Pen            Closed
Pencil         Closed
```

I am looking for a query which gives me an output as shown below:

```
Category      Open       Closed
Pen           1          1
Pencil        1          1
```

So far I tried, 
SELECT Category, COUNT(Status='Open'), Count(Status='Closed') FROM table GROUP BY Category;
This query does not solve the issue.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to do conditional aggregation using the `sum` and `iif` functions:

```
select 
  category, 
  sum(iif(status='Open',1,0)) as Open,
  sum(iif(status='Closed',1,0)) as Closed,
from table
group by category
```